# How long should the guarantee last to have to replace no more than 4% of the devices?

Tags: probability

I'm struggling with a math problem and need help.

Quality control for Comfort-Ease Computer Peripherals, Inc. has done studies showing that its voice recognition device has a mean life of 6.87 years with a standard deviation of 2.2 years. The manufacturer will replace any such device that wears out during the guarantee period.

How long should the guarantee run if the manufacturer wishes to replace no more than 4% of the devices?

I tried finding the z-score and got 0.9227

Comment: I tried to find the z score but I'm still very lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to have the tail of the distribution below $\mu-k\sigma$  be $0.04$ of the area and trying to find $k$ to make it so.  My z-score table gives the area from $\mu$ to $\mu+z\sigma$.  If that area is $0.46$ there will be $0.04$ in each tail.  I find $z\approx 1.75$ so the warranty should last $6.87-1.75\cdot 2.2=3.02$ years.  As the standard deviation is only given to one place, I would round this to $3.0$ years.